# Как сортировать по нескольким полям?

Tags: java, kotlin

У меня есть 3 объекта, например:
FIRST("DDD". "EEE"),
SECOND(null, "CCC"),
THIRD("AAA", "BBB")

Мне нужно отсортировать эти объекты по первой переменной (т.е. где "AAA", null и "DDD"), а если там встречается null (а он встречается), то брать для сортировки второе поле в этом объекте (т.е. "CCC"). Результатом сортировки должно быть:
THIRD("AAA", "BBB"),
SECOND(null, "CCC"),
FIRST("DDD". "EEE")
т.е. "AAA" -> "CCC" -> "DDD"

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать такую сортировку? Желательно на Котлин, но можно и на Java, потом что-нибудь похожее напишу на Котлине

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вы не пояснили где у располагаются объекты, но в любом случае для нетривиальной сортировки нужно либо реализовать интерфейс Comparable или создать свой Comparator. Более подробно [здесь](https://www.baeldung.com/java-sorting).

Comment: `list.sortedWith(compareBy<MyClass> { it.first ?: it.second })`

Comment: `val sortList = list.sortedBy { it.a ?: it.b  }`

Answer (score 0):

Представленный класс очень похож на енум вида:

```java
@Getter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@ToString
enum Foo {
    FIRST("DDD", "EEE"),
    SECOND(null, "CCC"),
    THIRD("AAA", "BBB"),
    NULL(null, null);

    private final String foo;
    private final String bar;
}
```

Отсортировать список/массив значений данного енума в указанном порядке можно при помощи обычного компаратора `Comparator.comparing`, в котором для сравнения будет подставляться нужное поле:

```java
List<Foo> list = Arrays.asList(Foo.FIRST, Foo.SECOND, Foo.THIRD);

list.sort(Comparator.comparing(f -> f.getFoo() == null ? f.getBar() : f.getFoo()));

System.out.println(list);
// -> [Foo.THIRD(foo=AAA, bar=BBB), Foo.SECOND(foo=null, bar=CCC), Foo.FIRST(foo=DDD, bar=EEE)]
```

---

Если полей для сортировки больше и все они могут принимать значение `null`, то может понадобиться использование компаратора `Comparator.nullsLast` после поиска первого не-нуллового значения:

```java
List<Foo> list2 = Arrays.asList(Foo.NULL, Foo.FIRST, Foo.SECOND, Foo.THIRD);
list2.sort(Comparator.comparing(
                f -> Stream.of(f.getFoo(), f.getBar())
                           .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                           .findFirst()
                           .orElse(null),
                Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder())
          )
);
```

> `[Foo.THIRD(foo=AAA, bar=BBB), Foo.SECOND(foo=null, bar=CCC), Foo.FIRST(foo=DDD, bar=EEE), Foo.NULL(foo=null, bar=null)]`